# Delete Image from Media Folder

Tags: magento-1.9, database, image, media

**insert action**

```
public function fanbookAction(){
        $img = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('img');
                if(isset($_FILES['img']['name'])) 
                {
                    try{
                       $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
                         $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); 
                         $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                         $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                         $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'FanBook'.DS;
                         $destFile = $path.'/'.$_FILES['img']['name'];

                         $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                         $uploader->save($path, $filename);
                         $img ='FanBook/'.$filename;

                          $collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');
                          $collection ->setData('img',$img);
                           $collection->save();

                         $this->_redirectReferer();
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Done');
                    }

                    catch(Exception $e) {

                    }


                }
    }
```

**Delete Action**

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
            try {
                $fanbookModel = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');

                $fanbookModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

While Deleteing I want to Delete Media folder also How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in delete action

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
        try {


            $fanbookModel = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

            $image = $fanbookModel->getImg();

            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS;

            unlink($path.$image);

            $fanbookModel->delete();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No it's not delete Media imgae

Comment: Mention your media image path in question

Comment: Yes it Shows two time FanBook root\media\FanBook\FanBook/imgname.jpg): No such file or directory

Comment: Check updated answer